# Solr filter query on multi valued field that may be empty

Tags: solr

Each of my indexed documents has a multi valued field `user_ids_ims` that contains user ids to which the document is related. This field may be empty.

```
<types>
  <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.IntPointField" omitNorms="true"/>
</types>

<fields>
  <dynamicField name="*_ims" type="tint" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>
```

I want a filter query for all the documents where `user_ids_ims` contains a particular id value, say `42`, or is empty. e.g. for the following documents:

```
{ id: 'Page 1', user_ids_ims: [] }
{ id: 'Thing 1', user_ids_ims: [19, 24, 92] }
{ id: 'Thing 2', user_ids_ims: [19, 24, 42, 92] }
{ id: 'Thing 7', user_ids_ims: [19, 24, 92] }
```

How do I use `fq` to include the set of documents including `Page 1` and `Thing 2`?

I can get `Page 1` using `fq=!user_ids_ims:[* TO *]`

I can get `Thing 2` using `fq=user_ids_ims:(42)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual answer is that you combine the two requirements:

```
fq=user_ids_ims:(42) OR (*:* -user_ids_ims:[* TO *])
```

The latter `*:*` is important, since you have to have a set of documents to subtract the set returned by `user_ids_ims:[* TO *]` from. This will give you any documents that have `42` in the field, or do not have the field at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `user_ids_ims` field is populated using values from a MySQL column defined with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so I know that `0` is not a valid `id`. With this knowledge, I can assign:

```
{ id: 'Page 1', user_ids_ims: [0] }
```

Now I have 2 defined values to search for, which is just fine, i.e. `fq=user_ids_ims:(0 42)`